# Stuck at the process to complete a Basic Web Development Project

Tags: html, server, frameworks, frontend, web-development-server

**Background:**

I've been given a project to make an small employee portal for an organization. This is a Full Stack Web Development project, since the only thing provided to me are excel worksheets as the organization's data. It has to be run within the organization, with multiple users using it at the same time.

**Project Deadline:** 28th June ~ 10 days

**Problem:**

I've never made a web development project before. I have very basic knowledge of Dreamweaver Tool, html, JavaScript. My programming skills are fine in general, and I'm competent in C#, good at C++.

What should I do to complete this project? I am all for learning everything and understanding all the languages, but just searching through the process; Making a Front End, Server,.. and all these different frameworks - I'm panicking and don't know what is my next step to take.

I've mapped all the business flows and made a prototype. I just need to start the actual development, but I don't know which next step to take.

Comment: Pass the project and money to me XD

Comment: Do you have good knowledge of RDBMS e.g. MySql, If yes then I can let you know something that can help you.

Comment: @Nishant yeah I do. I've worked on MySql before.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a good knowledge of relational DBMS then you can use CakePHP to create your application quickly. It provides a feature called Cake Bake that can generate the source code for complete application using CLI.

You can refer:

https://cakephp.org/

https://book.cakephp.org/bake/1.x/en/index.html

This will really help you for the rapid application development. I hope this will help you.